How to auto fill a date field value from the referenced entity's same-name date field?
I have 2 content types: book and bookwork. They both have a same date field published_date. The bookwork has an entity reference field referenced to the book content type. I'd like to achieve this: if user does not input the published_date in the bookwork node form, then it will automatically get the value from the referenced book's published_date field when saved.
How to make it? Many thanks!
